# for each category row products

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

i'm having 3 tables.

module_names (module_id , module_name, module_content)

module_groups (group_id,group_name,group_content)

module_to_group (module_id,group_id)

I'm using the following query to get the results:

```
$result = $db->sql_query("select 
m.module_id, 
m.module_name, 
g.group_name 
from 
" . $prefix . "_mmmodule_names m ,  
" . $prefix . "_mmmodule_to_group m2g, 
" . $prefix . "_mmmodule_groups g 
where 
m.module_id = m2g.module_id 
and 
m2g.group_id = g.group_id 
and 
g.group_id = g.group_id 
order by 
m.module_id"); 
while($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result)) { 
$content .= '<div>' . $row['group_name'] . '</div>'; 

$content .= '<div>' . $row['module_name'] . '</div>'; 
} 
echo $content;
```

it output like this:

**Group1**

Module1

**Group1**

Module2

**Group2**

Module3

**Group2**

Module4

But i require it like this:

**Group1**

Module1

Module2

**Group2**

Module3

Module4

It has been a long time ago i made something like it.
For what i can remember i used for each.But of course the resources i had back then , are now not the top 10 search results anymore in google.
(Groupconcat is not an good idea for me to use)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = $db->sql_query("select m.module_id, m.module_name, g.group_name from " . $prefix . "_mmmodule_names m ,  " . $prefix . "_mmmodule_to_group m2g, " . $prefix . "_mmmodule_groups g where m.module_id = m2g.module_id and m2g.group_id = g.group_id and g.group_id = g.group_id order by m.module_id"); 

$modules = array();
while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result)) { 
    $modules[$row['group_name']][] = $row['module_name'];      
} 

foreach ($modules as $groupName => $moduleNames) {

    echo "<h2>$groupName</h2>";

    foreach ($moduleNames as $moduleName) {
        echo "<p>$moduleName</p>";
    }
}
```

Just remembering last group name will not suffice since they can be mixed, another solution may be to add ordering for the group name in your query, in that case you can be sure that groups won't mix.

Comment: Accepted your answer , as it became clear to me again.This is how i remembered somehow.The answer gave me the solution to create a dynamic menu from it.THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1):

Everything's very simple. Just "remember" the last group name, and don't echo it until you've got the next one.

```
$tmpGroupName = null;
$result = $db->sql_query("select m.module_id, m.module_name, g.group_name from " . $prefix . "_mmmodule_names m ,  " . $prefix . "_mmmodule_to_group m2g, " . $prefix . "_mmmodule_groups g where m.module_id = m2g.module_id and m2g.group_id = g.group_id and g.group_id = g.group_id order by m.module_id");
while($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result)) {

    if ($tmpGroupName != $row['group_name'])
    {
        $tmpGroupName = $row['group_name'];
        $content .= '<div>' . $row['group_name'] . '</div>';
    }

    $content .= '<div>' . $row['module_name'] . '</div>';
}
echo $content;
```

Comment: As your answer did what i asked, it was not usable for me to create a dynamic menu from it li ul li li ul li.Ofcourse it also can be that my knowledge for it is missing.All the blame to me for that.

Answer (score 0):

On solution could be to save state, by state I mean make a variable above the while loop and save groups title names is it (example `Group 1`) and at first iteration which the variable is null you can print title as well but for next iteration check and see if title in loop is equal to what is stored in the variable is which state is saved.
If they are equal you can pass printing title again and if not it means its new group coming and you can print title as well.

about content (for each title) you can print then in each iteration without any conditions.